# bash script at shutdown

Tags: bash, symbolic-link

I want to empty my Download folder at shutdown, so I created a simple bash script `/etc/init.d/empty_download_folder.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /home/USER/Downloads/*
```

then changed the permissions:

```
sudo chmod +x empty_download_folder.sh
```

Now created symbolic links so the script runs on shutdown and reboot:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/empty_download_folder.sh /etc/rc0.d/empty_download_folder
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/empty_download_folder.sh /etc/rc6.d/empty_download_folder
```

The bash script works, but does not run at shutdown/reboot

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 zesty

Comment: 17.04 uses systemd place your script at `/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/`

Answer (score 0):

Reread `man bash` - it says, in part,

```
When  a  login  shell  exits, bash reads and executes commands from the
file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
```

`~/.bash_logout` is a better place to put your cleanup.